# SimpleXMLElement->xpath() showing data that's not in the object

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I'm querying YouTrack's web service to get a list of issues. The response is XML that looks like this:

```
<issueCompacts>
    <issue id="XX-1">
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CustomField" name="Type">
            <value>Bug</value>
        </field>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CustomField" name="Bill-to">
            <value>NBS</value>
        </field>
    </issue>
    <issue id="XX-2">
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CustomField" name="Type">
            <value>New Feature</value>
        </field>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CustomField" name="Bill-to">
            <value>NBS</value>
        </field>
    </issue>
    [...]
</issueCompacts>
```

I take this XML, which actually contains five issues, and create from it a SimpleXMLElement object called $issuesObj (note the plural 'issues'). I then iterate over the issues:

```
foreach ($issuesObj as $issueObj) {
    [...]
} //foreach
```

Inside this loop (note the singular 'issue' for the as variable), if I var_dump() $issueObj, I get this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "XX-1"
  }
  ["field"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (2) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "Type"
      }
      ["value"]=>
      string(3) "Bug"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (2) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Bill-to"
      }
      ["value"]=>
      string(3) "NBS"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a dump of $issueObj->asXml():

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<issue id="XX-1">
    <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CustomField" name="Type">
        <value>Bug</value>
    </field>
    <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CustomField" name="Bill-to">
        <value>NBS</value>
    </field>
</issue>
```

So far, this is exactly as expected. But, this is where it gets weird. I want to pick out the field within the issue whose name is 'Type', so I'm using the xpath() method:

```
$typeField = $issueObj->xpath('//field[@name="Type"]')
```

Now, if I dump $typeField, I get this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Type"
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "Bug"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Type"
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(11) "New Feature"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Type"
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(11) "New Feature"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Type"
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "Bug"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Type"
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(11) "New Feature"
  }
}
```

Note that there are five elements instead of the expected two. What appears to be happening is that the xpath() method is acting on the original $issuesObj, not on the $issueObj that's a subset. But, it gets even more weird. If I convert $issueObj to XML, and then use that XML to go right back to an object, it works. Thus:

```
$issueObj = new \SimpleXMLElement($issueObj->asXml());
$typeField = $issueObj->xpath('//field[@name="Type"]');
var_dump($typeField); exit;
```

yields this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Type"
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "Bug"
  }
}
```

which is correct. And calling $typeField[0]->asXml() now yields this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CustomField" name="Type">
    <value>Bug</value>
</field>
```

which, again, is exactly as expected.

Any clues as to why SimpleXMLElement is behaving this way?

Comment: Here's someone else that had the same problem: <http://lenss.nl/2008/08/php5-simplexml-and-xpath/>. Sounds like an issue with PHP's implementation of xpath.

Comment: As per my answer, it's working exactly as it should.

Comment: I agree that it's working to spec, but as per my comments on your answer, I think this is one of those cases where the spec is wrong :-).

Comment: Do you mean that the XPath spec should have no way to search for elements from the root of the document when given a node within that document as its context? What about selecting parents and ancestors of the given node, which also require data from "outside" the context node?

Comment: Um, no. Don't be silly. I mean that the abstraction layer that is SimpleXML should provide an interface to the XML that is self-consistent from the POV of the userland PHP programmer. You described it yourself as a quirk that the other methods don't appear to know what's going on. Fixing it may mean fixing those other methods, but "how" isn't important here. What's important is that there are key behaviors in SimpleXML that can only be explained with knowledge of the underlying implementation, and which require an awareness of data that library users won't have. Those are problems.

Comment: I wasn't being silly: I genuinely don't know what you would expect to see working differently to make it "self-consistent". There could be a method on SimpleXMLElement called `->getDocument()` or `->getDocumentRoot()`, but this wouldn't "fix" `print_r` to somehow show the whole document. I think the only thing that's needs fixing is that the documentation for the `->xpath()` method should include the word "document" in its summary, as a reminder that that's how an XPath expression works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in how XPath handles *context*. [This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256199%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), although obviously talking about a completely different implementation, has a succinct explanation:

> An expression that uses the double forward slash (`//`) indicates a search that can include zero or more levels of hierarchy. When this operator appears at the beginning of the pattern, the context is relative to the root of the document.

So `foo//bar` starts at the "current" node, finds children called `foo` then recursively searches their descendants for `bar`; but `//bar` jumps to the top of the document, and searches recursively for any node at all which is called `bar`.

To refer to the current context explicitly, you can use a `.`, so `.//field[@name="Type"]` should work as you wanted.

Since, in your case, the `field` element is a direct child of the current node, you don't need the recursive `//` anyway, so `./field[@name="Type"]` and `field[@name="Type"]` should also work.

---

*Aditional note*: Your phrase "not in the object" in the title suggests that you are thinking of SimpleXML as having turned the XML file into a bunch of PHP objects. This isn't really the case; instead, think of SimpleXML as an API for manipulating a parsed XML document in memory, and each SimpleXMLElement as a pointer into that parsed document. The API is designed to feel "natural" within PHP, but contains a lot more "magic" than most PHP objects.

Comment: I understand what xpath is doing. What I don't understand is how: it's pulling data that doesn't exist in the object variable. Look at the object dump and XML dump immediately following the foreach() loop I gave, and note what data are present. The $issueObj variable contains a single issue, which contains two <field> nodes. This isn't a case of confused context; it's a case of pulling data from a context that doesn't exist. Seeing it now with fresh eyes, I think what's happening relates to the object being assigned by reference, and SimpleXMLElement traversing to the original variable.

Comment: @mr.w See the "additional note" at the end of my answer: the SimpleXML object does not "contain" anything, it is a pointer to a particular point in the parsed XML document in memory. This has nothing to do with "assigned by reference" or anything understandable in pure PHP, it's how the underlying C code works. The underlying XML library can perform a search on the whole document, as requested by the `//` at the start of the XPath expression, even though there is no PHP function that reveals the whole document.

Comment: Yes, it's an implementation quirk of how PHP implements xpath. The problem is that it has inconsistent consequences. If you are given a SimpleXMLElement object, and you call its asXml() method to see what XML it's representing, you expect to have other methods (in this case, xpath) operate only on that XML. But that's not the case, and there's no way for the programmer to know what the "true" XML is - even doing a var_dump() won't yield everything. Imagine the confusion when the object is passed up from a library. At the very least, this behavior needs to be clearly documented in userland.

Comment: It's more a quirk in the rest of SimpleXML, that it has no object representing the document, as in other APIs, such as the DOM - although even a DOM node wouldn't "contain" the whole document if you dumped it. XPath itself *always* works with reference to both a document and a context node, as demonstrated by the MSDN link I posted.

Comment: I think it's arguable whether it's SimpleXML's xpath that's out of whack or whether it's the rest of SimpleXML. Either way, it really doesn't matter: there's a definite inconsistency that, as I said, should be well documented, at least, and ideally, addressed in PHP. A userland programmer shouldn't have to have any knowledge about the underlying implementation of SimpleXML, xpath, or anything else to be able to predict and understand what their code is going to do. That said, you've explained the problem expressed in my question, so this is the answer.

Comment: @mr.w I don't really think it's an inconsistency, or see how it could be "fixed": the SimpleXMLElement is not a document, and should not act as though it is. It represents a node within a particular document, just as a DOMNode would - modifying the element modifies the document, for instance. [The documentation for the `->xpath()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) could perhaps be tweaked to make clear that (*like any XPath implementation*) the expression is searching the current document using the node as context, not just searching "within" the node itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the xpath syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp
For example: //title[@lang] Selects all the title elements that have an attribute named lang

Change this :

```
$typeField = $issueObj->xpath('//field[@name="Type"]');
```

to this :

```
$typeField = $issueObj->xpath('field[@name="Type"]');
```

Comment: Once again, w3schools isn't a particularly great reference here: their description of `//` includes the rather ambiguous phrase "nodes in the document from the current node", which doesn't really clear much up.

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the question of why SimpleXML is behaving in the described way, but it's still useful for others who may come seeking a good workaround (which this is) rather than a behind-the-scenes explanation (as I was). Up-voted.